# Default for text element in zf2 forms

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-form

How can I setup default for Text element in ZF2 Forms?

I tried the following:

1. In the view file. This does not get to data, and is not saved:

   ```
   if($form->get('agencyName')->getValue() === '')
       $form->get('agencyName')->setValue('Virtual Field Practicum');
   ```
2. This affects neither view, nor DB:

   ```
   $this->add(array(
           'name' => 'agencyName',

           'options' => array(
               'label' => 'Agency Name',
           ),
           'attributes' => array(
               'disabled' => 'disabled',
               'value' => 'Virtual Field Practicum',
           )
       ));
   ```
3. I also tried to modify entity in two ways, but it did not affect anything:

   ```
   public function __construct()
   {
       //set default agency name
       $this->agencyName = 'Virtual Field Practicum';
   }
   ```

OR:

```
   public function setAgencyName($agencyName)
    {
        if ($agencyName === '')
            $this->agencyName = 'Virtual Field Practicum';
        else
            $this->agencyName = $agencyName;

        return $this;
    }
```

**Edit 1**
Adding my generic actions to the post:

1) This one is responsible to load the forms, and process non-ajax calls:

```
public function editTabAction()
{
    $buildName = $this->params()->fromRoute('buildName', 'unknown');

    if ($buildName == 'unknown') {
        $buildName = $this->params()->fromPost('buildName', 'unknown');

        if ($buildName == 'unknown') {
            trigger_error('Could not retrieve build name for ' . $buildName . ' entity for this form!');
        }
    }

    //extract parameter from dispatch command
    $studEvalId = (int)$this->params()->fromRoute('studEvalId', 0);

    if ($studEvalId == 0) {
        //extract parameter from the form submission
        $studEvalId = (int)$this->params()->fromPost('studEvalId', 0);
        if ($studEvalId == 0) {
            return $this->notFoundAction();
        }
    }

    $data = $this->getEntity($buildName, $studEvalId);

    // Get your ObjectManager from the ServiceManager
    $objectManager = $this->getEntityManager();


    // get from from FormElementManager plugin
    //forms are defined in Module.php
    $formName = $buildName . "Form";
    $sl = $this->getServiceLocator();
    $form = $sl->get('FormElementManager')->get($formName);

    $form->setHydrator(new DoctrineHydrator($objectManager ));
    $form->setObject($this->getEntityInstanceFromBuildName($buildName));

    $form->bind($data);

    //set class and Id for buttons like SaveChanges to reference it
    $form->setAttribute('class', "studentFormsClass_$studEvalId");
    $form->setAttribute('id', "studentFormsId_$studEvalId" . "_$buildName");


    //set buildName to the form
    $form->get('buildName')->setAttribute('value', $buildName);

    $request = $this->getRequest();
    if ($request->isPost()) {
        $formValidatorName = "OnlineFieldEvaluation\Form\\" . $buildName . "FormValidator";
        $formValidator = new  $formValidatorName();
        $form->setInputFilter($formValidator->getInputFilter());

        $form->setData($request->getPost());

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $this->savetodb($form->getData(), $buildName);

            // Redirect to list of forms
            return false;
        } else {
            foreach ($form->getMessages() as $messageId => $message) {
                echo '<pre>';
                echo "Validation failure '$messageId':";
                print_r($message);
                echo '</pre>';
            }
        }
    }

    $view = new ViewModel(array(
        'studEvalId' => $studEvalId,
        'buildName' => $buildName,
        'form' => $form,
    ));
    $view->setTemplate('online-field-evaluation/tabs/edit' . $buildName . '.phtml');

    return $view;
}
```

2) This one is responsible for ajax calls:

```
    public function validatepostajaxAction()
    {

        $request = $this->getRequest();
        $response = $this->getResponse();

        $buildName = $this->params()->fromRoute('buildName', 'unknown');

        if ($buildName == 'unknown') {
            $buildName = $this->params()->fromPost('buildName', 'unknown');

            if ($buildName == 'unknown') {
                trigger_error('Could not retrieve build name for ' . $buildName . ' entity for this form!');
            }
        }

        //extract parameter from dispatch command
        $studEvalId = (int)$this->params()->fromRoute('studEvalId', 0);

        if ($studEvalId == 0) {
            //extract parameter from the form submission
            $studEvalId = (int)$this->params()->fromPost('studEvalId', 0);
            if ($studEvalId == 0) {

                return $this->notFoundAction();
            }
        }

        $data = $this->getEntity($buildName, $studEvalId);
        $objectManager = $this->getEntityManager();

        $formName = $buildName . "Form";
        $sl = $this->getServiceLocator();
        $form = $sl->get('FormElementManager')->get($formName);

        $form->setHydrator(new DoctrineHydrator($objectManager ));
        $entityName = 'OnlineFieldEvaluation\Entity\\' . $buildName;
        $form->setObject(new $entityName());

        $form->bind($data);

        //set class and Id for buttons like SaveChanges to reference it
        $form->setAttribute('class', "studentFormsClass_$studEvalId");
        $form->setAttribute('id', "studentFormsId_$studEvalId" . "_$buildName");


        //set buildName to the form
        $form->get('buildName')->setAttribute('value', $buildName);

        $messages = array();
        if ($request->isPost()) {
            $formValidatorName = "OnlineFieldEvaluation\Form\\" . $buildName . "FormValidator";
            $formValidator = new  $formValidatorName();
            $form->setInputFilter($formValidator->getInputFilter());

            $form->setData($request->getPost());

            if (!$form->isValid()) {
                $errors = $form->getMessages();
                foreach ($errors as $key => $row) {

                    if (!empty($row) && $key != 'submit') {
                        foreach ($row as $keyer => $rower) {
                            //save error(s) per-element that
                            //needed by Javascript
                            $messages[$key][] = $rower;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            if (!empty($messages)) {
                $response->setContent(
                    \Zend\Json\Json::encode(
                        array('status' => 'error',
                            'messages' => (array) $messages,
                            'buildName' => $buildName,
                            'studEvalId' => $studEvalId

                        )));

            } else {
                //save to db <span class="wp-smiley wp-emoji wp-emoji-wink" title=";)">;)</span>
                $this->savetodb($form->getData(), $buildName);
                $response->setContent(
                    \Zend\Json\Json::encode(
                        array(
                            'status' => 'success',
                            'messages' => 'Successfuly saved.',
                            'buildName' => $buildName,
                            'studEvalId' => $studEvalId
                        )
                    ));
            }
        }

        return $response;
    }
```

Comment: I suggest the best way to go about this is your attempt no. 3. However if this isn't affecting the form then perhaps the issue lies in your form hydration. Could you show how you're setting up your form in your controller?

Answer (score 2):

To setup a default value for an element, simply do the following:

- Open controller's action, that renders desired view
- Instantiate a form, get the element by its name and do call `setValue()` on that

That looks like as following:

```
public function addAction()
{
     $form = new YourAgencyForm();

     $form->get('agencyName')->setValue('Virtual Field Practicum');
     ....
```

It's really that simple

Comment: I have a generic action which generates all forms per User. I can create an if statement just for this form, but it sounds like a hack in my case. Should not it be possible to set it up in a form or in a view ?

Comment: When trying to set it all up in views or forms, it always gets overridden with empty values. That's just how it's done in ZF. So far, I've found only one way to handle that, and that's via actions, as I posted. And if you can create one if statement that does the job, you should probably do that. Yes that might look as a hack, but there's no another way to do the same, as far as I know.